# Slow mounting cifs-share

Tags: bash, networking

I wrote this simple script to save my daily screen-/worktime.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Make this as an alias for reboot & poweroff,
# so the complete uptime per day is logged
log="$HOME/.local/logs/worktime.log"
time=$(uptime -p)
date=$(date)

# append local log
echo "$date $time minutes" >> $log

# overwriting remote log
[[ -d $HOME/networkshare/username/logs ]] && cp $log $HOME/networkshare/username/logs/
```

I alias it to `reboot` and `poweroff`, so every time my system is shutdown or rebooted the uptime gets saved. In the last line I check if my networkshare is already connected, because I want the log also on my share. It is usually connected through an `automount`-unit. The file-system on the share is `cifs`.

Now the case is: that every time I want to access my networkshare, it takes some time to  load my files/folders on the networkshare. So always when I want to access my folders there, I need to wait around 2-4 minutes. With the last line I got wanted to get around this problem so I can save the log just locally if the share isn't available.

The problem is that this delays my `reboot` or `poweroff` by 2-4 minutes, if I haven't accessed the networkshare before.

Is there a way to mount the networkshare faster (right now I'm using this way: [Mount Network Drive with systemd on Startup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684937/mount-network-drive-with-systemd-on-startup)) or to check the availability of the share in a different way?

Thanks for reading!

EDIT:
I usually access three shares on boot, from which two of them scale around 216TB each. The smaller share only got 100GB. I disabled the *.automount-units for the bigger shares so I only access the small share.

I also added the options `noserverino` but I did not reduce the mount time.

EDIT2:
By using `Wireshark` I analyzed my network-connection when running `mount.cifs`. There are no significant errors and the time passed between the requests of my client and the responses of the share does not match my real waiting-time.

Comment: There is something wrong about your mounting if it takes 2 minutes or more! The point of a network file system is that you do not have to load all the files, but only access them as you need them. So, you'd honestly need to fix that.

Comment: But your mount setup looks correct. By the way, where does NTFS come into play here? I see not a single windows machine in what you describe!

Comment: @MarcusMüller the networkshare is usually accessed by windows-machines so I described it as ntfs

Comment: How long does it take for the windows clients to mount the share?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Windows client mount the drives immediately after boot.

Comment: Then there's probably something wrong with how your Linux machine is set up in terms of networking, but this is just a guess: mounting even gigantic directories via cifs really should only take a very short time!